# What is the python script to export the selected meshes in .obj?

Tags: python, scripting, export, obj

I want to export my selected meshes in .obj in a relative path from the .blend file in python.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj

Comment: ^ see that question for Blender 2.8 solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export multiple objects to .obj](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

export obj to relative file path script:

```
import bpy
import os

blend_file_path = bpy.data.filepath
directory = os.path.dirname(blend_file_path)
target_file = os.path.join(directory, 'myfile.obj')

bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=target_file)
```

further export obj options:

```py
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(
 filepath="",
 check_existing=True,
 axis_forward='-Z',
 axis_up='Y',
 filter_glob="*.obj;*.mtl",
 use_selection=False,
 use_animation=False,
 use_mesh_modifiers=True,
 use_edges=True,
 use_smooth_groups=False,
 use_smooth_groups_bitflags=False,
 use_normals=True,
 use_uvs=True,
 use_materials=True,
 use_triangles=False,
 use_nurbs=False,
 use_vertex_groups=False,
 use_blen_objects=True,
 group_by_object=False,
 group_by_material=False,
 keep_vertex_order=False,
 global_scale=1,
 path_mode='AUTO'
)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you it works. And how can i export it in a relative subfolder and an absolute path?

Comment: he script i gave you exports to the folder of the .blend file
if you want to ad a subfolder you can just add it in this line:

target_file = os.path.join(directory, 'subfolder', 'myfile.obj')

An absolute path you can provide as a string
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath="C:/path/to/file.obj")

Comment: I don't undertand which line i should replace. I want the user to type the absolute or relative path in the same place, then after the path it adds 'lod0_' then it takes the mesh's + name name = 'game_asset' and add + '.obj'.

Comment: export to directory subfolder dont work

Comment: This no longer works for Blender 4.0

Answer (score 2):

In Blender 4.0 and up, the operator `bpy.ops.export_scene.obj` no longer exists. Use [`bpy.ops.wm.obj_export`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.obj_export)

```
bpy.ops.wm.obj_export(
    filepath="filename.obj",
    check_existing=True,
    filter_blender=False,
    filter_backup=False,
    filter_image=False,
    filter_movie=False,
    filter_python=False,
    filter_font=False,
    filter_sound=False,
    filter_text=False,
    filter_archive=False,
    filter_btx=False,
    filter_collada=False,
    filter_alembic=False,
    filter_usd=False,
    filter_obj=False,
    filter_volume=False,
    filter_folder=True,
    filter_blenlib=False,
    filemode=8,
    display_type='DEFAULT',
    sort_method='DEFAULT',
    export_animation=False,
    start_frame=-2147483648,
    end_frame=2147483647,
    forward_axis='NEGATIVE_Z',
    up_axis='Y',
    global_scale=1.0,
    apply_modifiers=True,
    export_eval_mode='DAG_EVAL_VIEWPORT',
    export_selected_objects=False,
    export_uv=True,
    export_normals=True,
    export_colors=False,
    export_materials=True,
    export_pbr_extensions=False,
    path_mode='AUTO',
    export_triangulated_mesh=False,
    export_curves_as_nurbs=False,
    export_object_groups=False,
    export_material_groups=False,
    export_vertex_groups=False,
    export_smooth_groups=False,
    smooth_group_bitflags=False,
    filter_glob='*.obj;*.mtl'
)
```

Answer (score -5):

See if that helps you :

[How to write a simple Wavefront-OBJ exporter in Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32468/how-to-write-a-simple-wavefront-obj-exporter-in-python)

Or you can simply use the export button in blender :

[image]

And make sure "Selectio Only" is checked
 [image]