# How can I export object (.obj) in Blender 4.0 via Python?

Tags: python, objects, export, obj

I used `bpy.ops.export_scene.obj` to export .obj files [like in this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84934/what-is-the-python-script-to-export-the-selected-meshes-in-obj) which works until Blender 3.6. Now when I check the [export documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html), this operator is gone.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to tick show python tooltips, there I can see it `bpy.ops.wm.obj_export`

Comment: updated https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/309888/142292